# Android Autofocus Callback

Tags: java, android

I am working with project which detects whether the camera is successful in autofocus. I want to call a function (Toast at the moment) everytime the camera autofocus in an object. I uses the code below but it only work at first attempt. When I try to focus the cam again, the function is not being called.

CameraView.java

```
package com.example.xx.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.hardware.Camera.AutoFocusCallback;

import java.io.IOException;

public class CameraView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;
    public CameraView(Context context, Camera camera){
        super(context);

        mCamera = camera;
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        //get the holder and set this class as the callback, so we can get camera data here
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_NORMAL);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        try{
            //when the surface is created, we can set the camera to draw images in this surfaceholder
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();

            mCamera.autoFocus(new AutoFocusCallback() {
                public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "This is my Toast message!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("ERROR", "Camera error on surfaceCreated " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i2, int i3) {
        //before changing the application orientation, you need to stop the preview, rotate and then start it again
        if(mHolder.getSurface() == null)//check if the surface is ready to receive camera data
            return;

        try{
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e){
            //this will happen when you are trying the camera if it's not running
        }

        //now, recreate the camera preview
        try{
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();



            mCamera.autoFocus(new AutoFocusCallback() {
                public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "This is my Toast message!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("ERROR", "Camera error on surfaceChanged " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        //our app has only one screen, so we'll destroy the camera in the surface
        //if you are unsing with more screens, please move this code your activity
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.release();
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.xxx.myapplication;

import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static java.security.AccessController.getContext;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Camera mCamera = null;
    private CameraView mCameraView = null;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {
            mCamera = Camera.open();//you can use open(int) to use different cameras
            Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
//*EDIT*//params.setFocusMode("continuous-picture");
            params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
            mCamera.setParameters(params);

            mCamera.autoFocus(new Camera.AutoFocusCallback() {
                public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This is my Toast message!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("ERROR", "Failed to get camera: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        if(mCamera != null) {
            mCameraView = new CameraView(this, mCamera);//create a SurfaceView to show camera data
            FrameLayout camera_view = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.camera_view);
            camera_view.addView(mCameraView);//add the SurfaceView to the layout
        }
    }
}
```

What's wrong with code?

Comment: you call autofocus only onCreate. You have to call it again (by time? on button click?) to autofocus again.

Comment: @VladMatvienko I want to show the toast everytime the camera autofocus.

Comment: Ok, the callback will be called only once, when camera autofocuses for your `mCamera.autoFocus` call. If you want it to continue focusing with a callback, you will have to call `mCamera.autoFocus` again manually.

Comment: @VladMatvienko Can you help me to modify my code?

Comment: I can help, but I won't do it instead of you. What is a problem?

Comment: @VladMatvienko I'm sorry but I don't know what to do. I'm new in android.

Comment: I won't do it instead of you in any case. Basically you need to call autofocus each time you get a callback.

Comment: @VladMatvienko can you please help my code to show toast everytime the camera focuses? It would be a big help to me.

Comment: No, it won't be a big help. I will just do your work instead of you. It is twice bad thing. Firstly, you want me to do the work, for which you will get some benefits. It isn't honest. And secondly it is bad because you won't become good developer unless you don't start solving problems by yourself. So there are 2 solutions: 1) you can go to some freelance web site, and hire somebody to do it instead of you for money. 2) You try doing it by yourself, and asking other guys for *help*, not *to give you complete code*. We'll be happy to **help**

Comment: Again: you call `mCamera.autoFocus`, which will fire a callback once it autofocuses. Inside that callback you need to call `mCamera.autoFocus` with a callback again, and in that callback to call `mCamera.autoFocus` again, and so on

Comment: I created a function focus() and put the autoFocus() inside it. Then i called the focus() inside focus()->autoFocus(). It works! Thanks

Comment: see, that's much better than if i did it instead of you.